# Instagram profile_pic_url gives access denied

Tags: instagram, access-denied

I'm trying to log in the user using the official Instagram API and it works fine however one of the returned parameters is `profile_pic_url` supposedly its the user profile picture and an example of it:

`https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com//vp//f8206fb249e8f7b7f6fb396fb1e9a249//5CC9F33F//t51.2885-19//s150x150//43985395_2118840648146743_9220106684888776704_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com`

It's giving me HTTP 403.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to:
`https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/f8206fb249e8f7b7f6fb396fb1e9a249/5CC9F33F/t51.2885-19/s150x150/43985395_2118840648146743_9220106684888776704_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com`
change double slashes to single ones

Comment: How do I get larger versions of this pic?

Comment: I haven't worked with Instagram API. Search, and you'll get your answer